# DrawImage from one indexed Bitmap onto another C# .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, image, graphics, palette

I have two indexed (8-bits) Bitamp, both using the same Palette in C# (.NET Framework 2.0). I want to bit block copy pixels from one onto another on designated coordinates. I had tried to use Graphics class, but get exception that it doesn't work with indexed colors, I tried also with getpixel()/setpixel() but get the same exception.
It doesn't need to be quick it just have to work. And I CAN'T convert to non-indexed image and vice-versa - palette is very important for me and I can't loose any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI+ supports indexed formats *very* poorly.  Things got better with Vista which included an update to gdiplus.dll to version 1.10.  Nothing you should could on I imagine.  You could hack Bitmap.Lock(), dealing with the single byte-per-pixel format is doable.  But get these images into a 24 or 32bpp format I'd say.

Comment: As I said - I can't: even change of the order of colors in palette is unacceptable

Answer (score 1):

You may use the http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Comment: Sorry, but this is not acceptable - imagemagick's alters my palette settings (as I said, I must by absolutely sure that palette won't change, ie. the order of colors will be kept)